# xslt info capturing

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a xml input like below:

```
<food>
  <fruit>Orange</fruit>
    isGood
  <fruit>Kiwi</fruit>
    isGood
  <fruit>Durian</fruit>
    isBad
</food>
```

i want to transform it to a html statement like below:

*Orange* isGood. *Kiwi* isGood. *Durian* isBad.

please note that the fruits element are all in italic.

the code that i have is like below.but its having problem.

```
  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <food>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="food"/>
    </food>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="food">
    <xsl:element name="fruit"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="fruit" /> 
    </xsl:element>        
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You input XML doesn't look good as in between text doesn't seem to belong to fruit node

Comment: hi yog,yes the text isGood and isBad is not inside the fruit node.it is inside the food node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your XSLT is trying to reproduce the original input instead of producing HTML output like you want.

Here's an example of one way to do it...

**XML Input**

```
<food>
    <fruit>Orange</fruit>
    isGood
    <fruit>Kiwi</fruit>
    isGood
    <fruit>Durian</fruit>
    isBad
</food>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="food">
        <html>
            <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fruit">
        <i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',normalize-space(following-sibling::text()),'. ')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output** (raw)

```
<html>
   <p><i>Orange</i> isGood. <i>Kiwi</i> isGood. <i>Durian</i> isBad. 
   </p>
</html>
```

**HTML Output** (browser display)

*Orange* isGood. *Kiwi* isGood. *Durian* isBad.